# What's the difference between TypeName="API.MyClass+Clients" and TypeName="API.MyClass.Clients" in asp:ObjectDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, objectdatasource

I have the following `asp:ObjectDataSource` declaration :

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="ODS_Data"
     SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="API.MyClass+Clients"/>
```

What's the difference between `TypeName="API.MyClass+Clients"` and `TypeName="API.MyClass.Clients` ?

The `.` vs the `+` .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` is for a class that belongs to a namespace directly. the `+` is for a nested class, eg:

```
public namespace MyClass
{
    public class Clients{}
}
```

Would lead to: `Myclass.Clients`

While

```
public class MyClass
{
    public class Clients{}
}
```

Would lead to: `MyClass+Clients`